Unable to customise points in itemise inside twocolumn option argument
I am unable to use an itemize environment within the \twocolumn argument with custom markers such as \item[Q] and \item[A]:
This is my minimal error code:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\twocolumn[

\begin{itemize}
\item[Q] Name five countries
\vspace{-0.3cm}
\item[A] South Africa, Kenya, Zimbabwe, Mexico, and Japan
\end{itemize}

]
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}

When I run this code, these are the errors I find in the .log file:
! Argument of \@item has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.8 \item[A]
             Open up
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.

Runaway argument?
A\vskip -\dbltextfloatsep 
! Paragraph ended before \@item was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.8 \item[A]
             Open up
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.

! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
<recently read> }
                 
l.8 \item[A]
             Open up
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.


! LaTeX Error: Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.10 \item[M]
              Close down
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.


! LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{itemize}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.11 \end{itemize}
                  
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.


Underfull \hbox (badness 3826) in paragraph at lines 15--15
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 Quisque ul-la-m-cor-per pla-ce-rat ip-sum.
 []

(./Test.aux)
 ***********
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-02-20>
 ***********

! You can't use `\end' in internal vertical mode.
\enddocument ...cument/end}\deadcycles \z@ \@@end 
                                                  
l.15 \end{document}
                   
Sorry, but I'm not programmed to handle this case;
I'll just pretend that you didn't ask for it.
If you're in the wrong mode, you might be able to
return to the right one by typing `I}' or `I$' or `I\par'.

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.15 \end{document}
                   
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.

! Extra \endgroup.
<recently read> \endgroup 
                          
l.15 \end{document}
                   
Things are pretty mixed up, but I think the worst is over.

)


You can wrap the content in an additional group {...} to hide the square brackets:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\twocolumn[{

\begin{itemize}
\item[Q] Name five countries
\vspace{-0.3cm}
\item[A] South Africa, Kenya, Zimbabwe, Mexico, and Japan
\end{itemize}

}]
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}


